# Rails routes optional parameters losing data?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a route on RoR 5.1.4:

```
  get '/search(/:profile_type(/:tag(/:country)))', to: "search#index", as: "search"
```

I'd expect that:

```
[3] pry(main)> app.search_path(country: 'test')
=> "/search?country=test"
```

but it is:

```
[3] pry(main)> app.search_path(country: 'test')
=> "/search"
```

Losing the 'country' parameter. Am I missing something here? If it's a bug it's massive, I hope I'm mistaking

```
[4] pry(main)> app.search_path(tag: 'whatever', country: 'test')
=> "/search"
[5] pry(main)> app.search_path(test: 'test')
=> "/search?test=test"
[6] pry(main)> app.search_path(profile_type: 'test1', tag: 'test2', country: 'test3')
=> "/search/test1/test2/test3"
[7] pry(main)> app.search_path(profile_type: 'test1', tag: 'test2', country: 'test3', test: 'test')
=> "/search/test1/test2/test3?test=test"
```

Comment: Bug present since 2012? https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/7047

Comment: You can't expect the same route to accept `country` as an url (in case `profile_type` and `tag` are set) and as a GET parameter in case `profile_type`/`tag` are blank. It's over complicated and can lead to a bunch of other bugs. Trust me, it's absolutely NOT a massive bug. Mostly like a restriction to make things more clear and not overcomplicated. I have strong doubts, that `/search?country=test` would be so obvious result for all devs

Comment: Sure, losing data is way more obvious :-D

Comment: Anyway it's clearly a bug, and I've linked the discussion on RoR bug tracker where 3 RoR core members say so.

Comment: I don't want to say, that it's smth really trivial and obvious. If I were you I would think the same in such situation, but when I look out of the issue, it cab be logically. You still can get the result you want defining additional routes

Comment: Can you please post me link for this discussion. I am still curious to follow it.

Comment: First comment I made